# Equation to find minimum difference between given date and array of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to write an equation that compares a date to an array of other dates given the same ID and then returns the minimum value found between 0 and 42 or returns a zero if the criteria does not match.

My current equation can identify whether a date pair matches the above criteria and returns a 1 if there is a match and a 0 for no match.

`=IF(E15<>"",IFERROR(--(AGGREGATE(15,7,(E15-$H$2:$H$8000)/(($C$1:$C$8000=C15)*(E15-$H$2:$H$8000>=0)),1)<43),0),0)`

I need to modify this equation to return the actual difference between the dates rather than just a 1 or 0.

I have been playing around with an equation like this:

`=IF(E3<>"", IFERROR(IF(--(AGGREGATE(15, 6, (E3-$H$2:$H$8000)/(--($C$2:$C$8000=C3)*--(E3-$H$2:$H$8000>=0)), 1)<43)=1, MIN(--($C$2:$C$8000=C3)*(E3-$H$2:$H$8000)), ""), 0), 0)`

But it returns nothing but zeros.

Please find sample data and expected values below.

[image]

Comment: remove the `<43`

Comment: `=IF(E15<>"",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,7,(E15-$H$2:$H$8000)/(($C$1:$C$8000=C15)*(E15-$H$2:$H$8000>=0)*(E15-$H$2:$H$8000<43)),1),0),0)`

Comment: As always, I am amazed by your prowess, @ScottCraner. But is there a way to make it so the blanks in the above sample data image are blanks rather than zeros? Since there is a difference between having a difference of 0 and not having data.

Comment: Change the last `,0` to `,""`

Comment: Not to continue being a bother, but now it just fills a 0 in J wherever D<>0 and there is no legitimate difference between dates.

Comment: Then change the other `,0` to `,""`

Comment: I really appreciate your help, Scott. If you want to write it up, I will give your answer the credit. Otherwise, I will answer it using your answer (and giving you credit, of course) to help future people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want you only need to move the check for less than 43 into the Aggregate and return blanks instead of `0`:

```
=IF(E15<>"",IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,7,(E15-$H$2:$H$8000)/(($C$1:$C$8000=C15)*(E15-$H$2:$H$8000>=0)*(E15-$H$2:$H$8000<43)),1),""),"")
```